# Add a ExpandableListView into a fragment

Tags: android

I am developing an app for honeycomb, and I have put some tabs in the action bar, but now I don't know how to put an ExpandableListView in one of the tabs, or, in one of the fragments.

Answer (score 1):

ExpandableListView is not supported in fragments for now. You have to subclass Fragment for this. If you don't want to reinvent the wheel, take a look at this: https://gist.github.com/1316903

Answer (score 1):

Here is what is works for me:

Inside of Fragment

```
private String[] categories;
private String[][] categoryItems;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    categories = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.videos_curriculum);

    String[] category1 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.video_category1);
    String[] category2 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.video_category2);
    String[] category3 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.video_category3);
    categoryItems = new String[][]{category1, category2, category3};

}


@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    listView = (ExpandableListView) view.findViewById(R.id.expListView);
    listView.setAdapter(new VideoGroupsListAdapter(categories, categoryItems));
    listView.setGroupIndicator(null); // I don't need group indicator on left
}
```

**, inner class:**

```
public class VideoGroupsListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
    private final LayoutInflater inflater;
    private String[] groups;
    private String[][] children;

    public VideoGroupsListAdapter(String[] groups, String[][] children) {
        this.groups = groups;
        this.children = children;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return groups.length;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return children[groupPosition].length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return groups[groupPosition];
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return children[groupPosition][childPosition];
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_video_header, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.headerTitleTxt);
            holder.icon = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.headerIconTxt);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.text.setText(getGroup(groupPosition).toString());
        if (isExpanded) {
            holder.icon.setText(R.string.ic_down);
        } else {
            holder.icon.setText(R.string.ic_up);
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_video_list_item, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.titleTxt);
            holder.icon = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.watchedIconTxt);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.text.setText(getChild(groupPosition, childPosition).toString());

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView text;
        TextView icon;
    }

}
```

new_videos_header.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    style="@style/ListItem.Header.Light"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/default_scr_side_padding"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/default_scr_side_padding"
    >

    <!--Title-->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/headerTitleTxt"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingLeft="8dip"
        style="@style/HeaderTitle.Dark"
        />

    <!--Right Icon-->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/headerIconTxt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/ic_up"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```