# How to add ExpandableListView into Fragment

Tags: android

I am a newbie. I know that an ExpandableListView cannot be loaded into a Fragment.
I have a navigation Drawer and i want to add a ExpandableListView into it.
Should i use Frame Layout containing ExpandableListView into fragment or use another methodology. What i mean to say that i want to merge a module from one of project containing expandable view on main activity with the empty project only containing navigation drawer.

Comment: Contents are added twice to bypass  poor quality standard error.

Comment: i want to add my ExpandableListView into fragment used in  NavigationDrawer

Comment: `I know that an ExpandableListView cannot be loaded into a Fragment.` **WHO told you** that?! Tell them that **I can** load my ExpandableListViews inside my Fragments!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6918169/add-a-expandablelistview-into-a-fragment @DerGolem

Comment: Can you give me a direction to move forward

Comment: You already have an answer in the link you posted: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17439535/2649012

Comment: When we add a navigation drawer to our activity automatically it uses fragment. but i want to add expandableListView rather than ListView. How can i do this.

Comment: Read that answer agai... It's an **ExpandableListView**, even if the **call** it `listView` (some people uses **stupid names** for things): `listView = (ExpandableListView) view.findViewById(R.id.expListView);` They just forgot to declare it somewhere... `ExpandableListView listView;`

Comment: Some times answers are right in front of us, But we can't see. I am new to android. can you please explain little more. Thanks and respect for you.

Comment: I would have called it `expSomething` (depending on what the View is about to contain). I use to prefix object variables, since I have a strong .NET Certification background.

Comment: Is their any other alternatives

Comment: To what? To an ExpandableListView? Not as per the standard widgets, AFAIK.

Comment: to add category and sub category based list to add inside Drawer Layout.

Comment: But the principle is simple. You list the parents. When you click a parent, you list its children.